# how to use valuestate in xml view>

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have valueState atrribute in my input element:

```
valueState="{= ${myModel>/myProperty} > 0 ?'None':'Error' }"
```

this seem to work. But I want to modify my property first, before comparison to 0 like this:

```
valueState="{= $ parseFloat({myModel>/myProperty}.replace(',','.')) > 0 ?'None':'Error' }"
```

basically i want to modify string and convert myProperty to number before comparing with 0 to set value state

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, the correct syntax would be the following.

```
valueState="{= parseFloat(${myModel>/myProperty}.replace(',','.')) > 0 ?'None':'Error' }"
```

The dollar sign is the sign for the expression binding to read from a model.